# Nested library namespace in CMake

Tags: cmake, namespaces

When I see CMake libraries with namespaces they are always in the form
`Parent::Component`.

If I have a sufficiently large library, there may be subsections of that library that have components. I am wondering if it is possible/appropriate to do something like `ParentProject::Subgouping::SpecificComponent` or for a more real world example `Raytracing::Math::Utils`.

In short, can I use multiple namespaces in a CMake library name? If it is possible, is it a good idea?

Comment: "can I use multiple namespaces in a CMake library name?" - I see nothing which could prevent such usage. Have you tried to do that? Technically, aside a simple self-check, CMake doesn't tread ``::`` in a specific manner. "When I see CMake libraries with namespaces they are always in the form `Parent::Component`." - More correctly, the pattern is ``Package::LibraryName``. The part before colons denotes a **package**, (not a "parent" project or whatever) and the part after colons is the **library** (not a "component").

Comment: @Alec Note that even boost with it's 47 components doesn't try to do something like this. Probably best to avoid the extra "namespace" and use a different separator: `Raytracing::Math_Utils`. Not sure if there are possible issues with some generators/compilers/cpack generators, if you don't restrict yourself to a single `::`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short, can I use multiple namespaces in a CMake library name?

Yes. A colon (`:`) is just like any other character in a CMake target name. *However*, the `target_link_libraries` command will interpret any argument containing `::` in its name as a proper CMake target, rather than as a potential system library. So if you mis-type a target name or it otherwise doesn't exist, you'll get a useful error at configure time, rather than a broken build.

Having multiple instances of `::` in the name behaves the same as having just one.

> If it is possible, is it a good idea?

It's about as good an idea as nested namespaces are in C++. If it makes sense, do it. The only minor difference is that CMake has no `using namespace` equivalent, so they're slightly less convenient to type.

In several of my projects, I use a namespace like `Project::Tools::` to hold any build-time tools (like custom code generators) that need to be built separately for the sake of cross-compilation (when `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` is not an option).